# How do I show different options on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dropdown

I have got a dropdown button and I want to show different options depending on whether the difference between the current number and the preceding number is negative or positive.

How can I fix my code to make this work?

```
<td id="diff" ng-model="diff">
  {{val1 - val2}}
</td>
<td>
  <div id="actnot">
    <select name='act_id' id="aktion_1">
      <option value='1' ng-show="diff <= 0">Option 1</option>
      <option value='2' ng-show="diff >= 0">Option 2</option>
      <option value='3' ng-show="diff >= 0">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Please share your controller part which inlcudes val1 and val2 and diff variable

Comment: Shouldn't you add `angular` tag to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init to define your diff value :

```
<td ng-init="diff = val1-val2">
  <div id="actnot">
    <select name='act_id' id="aktion_1">
      <option value='1' ng-show="diff <= 0">Option 1</option>
      <option value='2' ng-show="diff >= 0">Option 2</option>
      <option value='3' ng-show="diff >= 0">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

If it's not working (I didn't test the code) maybe you can do the diff inside your controller and add it to the $scope or model object.

Comment: diff is coming though  ng-model from controller

Comment: What I understand is that @LuMi is trying to add to define the diff variable from the result of `{{ var1 - var2}}` and attach it to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgsVw/152/)

I have used `ng-if` to hide and show options as `ng-show`, by default shows the first option

```
<select>
      <option value="one" ng-if="diff <= 0">One</option>
      <option value="two" ng-if="diff >= 0">Two</option>
      <option value="three" ng-if="diff >= 0">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use ng-if instead -

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("myCntr",function($scope){
$scope.val1 = 9;
  $scope.val2 = 7;
  $scope.diff = $scope.val1-$scope.val2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntr">
    <td id="diff">{{val1 - val2}}</td>
    <td>
      <div id="actnot">
        <select name='act_id' id="aktion_1">
          <option value='1' ng-if="diff <= 0">Option 1</option>
          <option value='2' ng-if="diff >= 0">Option 2</option>
          <option value='3' ng-if="diff >= 0">Option 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
   </td>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this,where the diff value is evaluated and then passed into the select tag,You also cannot assign a ng-model to a `<td>` tag

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{diff = val1 - val2}}
    <td>
      <div id="actnot">
        <select name='act_id' id="aktion_1">
          <option default>--Select--</option>
          <option value='1' ng-show="diff <= 0">Option 1</option>
          <option value='2' ng-show="diff >= 0">Option 2</option>
          <option value='3' ng-show="diff >= 0">Option 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
   </td>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.val1=3;
  $scope.val2=4;
});
</script>
```